# xamarin forms labs binding issue with listview and checkbox

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am experiencing binding issues with xamarin forms lab ([Xamarin-forms-labs](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs)) checkbox control. I have a listview which
points to a contacts datasource (this is an observable collection). In the list view I have 
a custom view cell "InviteItemCell" (see code below).

The binding does not appear to be working both ways i.e. it binds correctly when reading
the datasource and indicating which contacts are selected, however when selecting a contact
by checking the checkbox through the UI, the underlying contact object property does not change.

here is the definition of the listview:

```
var stack = new StackLayout ();
list.ItemsSource = App.Service.Contacts;
list.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate (typeof(InviteItemCell));
```

Here is the custom viewcell:

```
public class InviteItemCell : ViewCell
    {
        public InviteItemCell ()
        {
            var chkInvite = new CheckBox ()
            { 
                TextColor = Color.White
            };

            chkInvite.SetBinding (CheckBox.DefaultTextProperty, "FullName");
            chkInvite.SetBinding (CheckBox.CheckedProperty, "Selected");

            var layout = new StackLayout 
            {
                Padding = new Thickness(20, 0, 0, 0),
                Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
                Children = {chkInvite}
            };

            View = layout;
        }

        protected override void OnBindingContextChanged ()
        {
            View.BindingContext = BindingContext;
            base.OnBindingContextChanged ();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
chkInvite.SetBinding (CheckBox.DefaultTextProperty, "FullName", BindingMode.TwoWay);
chkInvite.SetBinding (CheckBox.CheckedProperty, "Selected", BindingMode.TwoWay);
```